# Working with ExtJS's 'gridviewdragdrop' plugin : how can I disable dragging children out of the parentNode?

Tags: drag-and-drop, grid, extjs4

Working with ExtJS's gridviewdragdrop plugin, how can I disable dragging children out of the parentNode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on 'beforedrop' event  check if the parent changed  so cancel the editing

```
beforedrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition,  dropFunction,  eOpts ){
            if(data.records[0].isLeaf()){//
if(data.records[0].parentNode.data.id!=overModel.parentNode.data.id) 
             return false;
 }
```